Brushless DC motor controller / ESC output, DC or AC for EU Low Voltage Directive?
The EU "Low Voltage Directive" applies to goods with an input or output voltage of over 50 volt AC or 75V DC.^1
My question is: Would the output of an ESC be considered AC or DC in this context? Eg. would an ESC with a 60V bus voltage fall under the LVD?
(1): https://single-market-economy.ec.europa.eu/sectors/electrical-and-electronic-engineering-industries-eei/low-voltage-directive-lvd_en
